Step-Children of the Prophet Muhammad (PBUH)
Did our Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) have stepchildren from his wives' previous marriages? If so, how many were there, and how did he treat them, according to hadiths and sirah?

Yes he did. For example it is recorded in ahadith that Umm Salamah had children from her previous marriage (Nasai 3254, Bukhari 5378,  Bukhari 3491, Bukhari 5107). Simarly Umm Habiba had children as it is apparent from her name, and her daughter has narrated a hadith from her (Musnad Ahmad 27413).
Their total number is not known for certain since not every person who existed is recorded in history and at times historians forget or misremember such trivial details and there are conflicting reports.
He would have treated them well, in the same way that he would treat any other Muslim:

حريص عليكم بالمؤمنين رءوف رحيم
he is concerned over you and to the believers is kind and merciful
— Quran 9:128

